# Overlay two listview with no transparency

Tags: android, listview

Ho I have two list view on a frame layout.
I want one overlay the other and it has not a transparent background.
I have do this

```
    <FrameLayout  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">  


     <ListView
        android:id="@+id/autocompleteCompany"
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:paddingLeft="30dip"

         >

    </ListView>
  <ListView
      android:id="@+id/list"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>
</FrameLayout>
```

but don't work correctly.
Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using `<RelativeLayout>` instead of `<FrameLayout>`

**Edit:**

To get rid of transparency you need to set the background color of the listView or the items in the listView's adapter. These questions would help you do that:

[Changing background color of ListView items on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217753/changing-background-color-of-listview-items-on-android)

[listview item background color change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9356845/listview-item-background-color-change)

Comment: Hi thank you for answer. Hi try the relative layout but have the same result.

Comment: what is happening exactly? the second list is not overlaying the other? or some other issue?

Comment: the second list overlay corectly the other but the background of the first is transparent and it can see the item of the other listview below.