# how to preserve listview selected/ clicked item color while scrolling?

Tags: android-layout, android-widget, android-listview

this is really a strange problem i came across several google searches which returned in vain .

Well i have a list view in which the selected item color should be changed while user click on the item.

This post helped me to change the list view selected item color. Now i am able to change the color while the item is clicked . But if i scroll the list view the color jumps out of selection.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12080202/1657093

If a item is selected say for instance the listview item on first row the last item is also gets selected while scrolling the item color keeps on moving to the item which i never selected.

here is the list view

```
<ListView
     android:id="@+id/loadedlist"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_above="@+id/horizontalScroll"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_below="@+id/Title"
     android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/sidepanel"
     android:scrollingCache="false">

    </ListView>
```

I use array adapter to populate the list view

ringlist.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter
             (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,rings));

and use list view's on click method to set the color ,

```
ringlist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
     @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try{
    String con;
        String s =  ringlist.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
        con = s.toLowerCase();
    String selectedFromList = con;
            int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(selectedFromList, "raw",    
            "com.example.android");

            }
    if (row != null) {
            row.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            }

           row = view;
               view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                }

       }  

        });
```

the above code does the job but while scrolling the list something goes wrong

please advice.

Answer (score 0):

This is common issue of Listview in android.
When we use checkbox/radio button in Listview Item after scrolling down or up, the selected position does gets changed at some different places.
The only solution to this till now is, we need to maintain the selected position in a arraylist(or to any structure you are comfortable).
And as you scroll up/down the list view, the getview does gets called.
So write code in your getview() to make checkbox items selected from arraylist.
Also dont use if-else condition in getview for convertview.

Answer (score 0):

Store clicked/selected positions in a set or array in your onItemClick() method. Write code to show clicked/selected items in getview() method of your adapter using stored positions.